# servlet.jar missing in TOMCAT installation

Tags: servlets, tomcat6

I've recently installed tomcat(6.0.35) at my machine. Server get installed & running fine. Now, was trying to run my [first servlet program](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26920&seqNum=4), but it started giving error.
I find that it is not able to find two packages:

- `javax.servlet.*;`
- `javax.servlet.http.*;`

On searching Net I found that these two packages are present in `servlet.jar` file which should be present in bin directory of TOMCAT Installation directory. 
This is puzzling me because in bin folder(`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin`) only following files are present

- `tcnative-1.dll`
- `Tomcat6w.exe`
- `Tomcat6.exe`
- `tomcat-juli.jar`
- `bootstrap.jar`

I dont know what should be my next step. I search my computer and not able to find `servlet.jar` anywhere. Please note Tomcat is running fine.

Comment: Why would they be in the bin directory? They're libraries, answer they're in the lib directory. When do you get this error? Sounds more like a compilation classpath issue.

Comment: It might help you [The Apache Tomcat 5.5 Servlet/JSP Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html). Look at **Catalina** section specially.

Answer (score 1):

its not `servlet.jar`, it is `servlet-api.jar` and it will be in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib`
if its not there you have to install tomcat once again.